# Predicate search in core data causes SIGABRT on second time through. NSBetweenPredicateOperatorType

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate

I am seeing a really strange behavior in core data.  I am doing a search for locations in core data (data store type is SQLite).  The query is to look for location objects within a specific area.  I am implementing the search as a **between** predicate.

```
NSExpression *lhs = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:keyPath];
NSExpression *rhs = [NSExpression expressionForVariable:@"MIN_MAX"];

NSPredicate *predicateTemplate = 
    [NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:lhs       
                                       rightExpression:rhs
                                            modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier
                                                 type:NSBetweenPredicateOperatorType
                                              options:0];

NSPredicate *predicate = [predicateTemplate predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:
                          [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:expressionArray forKey:@"MIN_MAX"]];
```

where expressions array is an array of 2 object, min in index 0, and max in index 1.  Each object in the array is an NSConstantValueExpression, defined as :

```
NSExpression *ex = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue : numberValue]
```

I am using the predicate in a NSFetchedResultsController, and the first time though works exactly as I expect.  The final predicate is something like this:

> *NSFetchRequest: 0x7394360 (entity: Location; predicate: (longitude
>   BETWEEN {-122.0767937067412,
>   -121.7137663065599} AND latitude BETWEEN {37.16973380897733,
>   37.45968675392614} ); sortDescriptors: (("(name, ascending, compare:)"));
>   limit: 20; type:
>   NSManagedObjectResultType; )*

And I get the results I want.

The second time this code is run (by pushing a second view on top, and closing that view.  This causes the view to reload).  The system crashes, with this error message.

> **-[NSConstantValueExpression compare:]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x71bbea0
>       2011-04-22 10:54:11.742 Wines[13667:207]**  Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[NSConstantValueExpression
>   compare:]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x71bbea0'*

Any suggestions?

Full stack below.

Thanks,

```
    *** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02f0bb99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0305b40e objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02f0d6ab -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02e7d2b6 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02e7ce72 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   Foundation                          0x002dd909 -[NSBetweenPredicateOperator performPrimitiveOperationUsingObject:andObject:] + 317
    6   Foundation                          0x0020aee4 -[NSComparisonPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 306
    7   Foundation                          0x00210ead -[NSCompoundPredicateOperator evaluatePredicates:withObject:substitutionVariables:] + 292
    8   Foundation                          0x00210d57 -[NSCompoundPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 254
    9   Foundation                          0x0020adac -[NSPredicate evaluateWithObject:] + 49
    10  CoreData                            0x0252ae08 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 1752
    11  Wines                               0x00021b27 -[MOListViewController listFRC] + 1034
    12  Wines                               0x000bb1e8 -[MOLocationSelectableListViewController numberOfSectionsInTableView:] + 36
    13  UIKit                               0x0061849c -[UITableViewRowData(UITableViewRowDataPrivate) _updateNumSections] + 111
    14  UIKit                               0x00618228 -[UITableViewRowData invalidateAllSections] + 66
    15  UIKit                               0x004d2880 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateRowData] + 113
    16  UIKit                               0x004cbe9c -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 105
    17  UIKit                               0x004d853c -[UITableView reloadData] + 773
    18  UIKit                               0x004d5724 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 42
    19  QuartzCore                          0x02a22481 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 177
    20  QuartzCore                          0x02a221b1 CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    21  QuartzCore                          0x02a220bd -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 111
    22  UIKit                               0x0050c94b -[UIViewController window:willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:] + 567
    23  UIKit                               0x004889bd -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:duration:force:] + 4159
    24  UIKit                               0x006fa67b -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 768
    25  UIKit                               0x0050f10d -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:withTransition:] + 2937
    26  UIKit                               0x00508402 -[UIViewController _tryRecursivelyPresentModalViewController:withTransition:] + 134
    27  UIKit                               0x005083c6 -[UIViewController _tryRecursivelyPresentModalViewController:withTransition:] + 74
    28  UIKit                               0x0050e8e6 -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:withTransition:] + 850
    29  Wines                               0x0002d7a9 -[MOViewController didSelectToOneSelectOneAtIndexPath:] + 2195
    30  Wines                               0x0002e843 -[MOViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 4219
    31  Wines                               0x0005544f -[MOPriceViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 1509
    32  UIKit                               0x004d4a48 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1140
    33  UIKit                               0x004cb32e -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 219
    34  Foundation                          0x001e021a __NSFireDelayedPerform + 441
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x02eecf73 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x02eee5b4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1364
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x02e4add9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x02e4a350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x02e4a271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    40  GraphicsServices                    0x035bf00c GSEventRunModal + 217
    41  GraphicsServices                    0x035bf0d1 GSEventRun + 115
    42  UIKit                               0x0046faf2 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    43  Wines                               0x00002814 main + 102
    44  Wines                               0x000027a5 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

Comment: Did some more searching, and this answer solved the problem.

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268272/nspredicate-between-with-nsdate-causes-nsdate-constantvalue-unrecognized-se/5269494#5269494>

Not sure why it works the first time.  but changing to AND fixed my problem.

Dave, if I know how to credit your answer here, I would....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here ya go...

`BETWEEN` operations are aggregate operations, and aggregate operations are not supported by Core Data.  You'll need to turn this into:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K >= %@ AND %K <= %@", keyPath, lowerBound, keyPath, upperBound];
```