# Core Data: fetching items is slow with predicate

Tags: sqlite, core-data, nsfetchrequest

For my iPhone application I set up a data model for Core Data. It contains one entity `Words` and its attributes are `language : String`, `length : Integer16` and `word : String`.

I prefilled my model's SQLite database with a word list (200k items) writing a separate iPhone application using the identical data model and coping the filled database to the main application.

Now using NSFetchedRequest I can query for managed objects as I like, but the results come in slow. I use the following method:

```
- (NSString *)getRandomWordLengthMin:(int)minLength max:(int)maxLength
{
    NSString *word = @"";

    MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];    
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Words"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSString *predicateString = @"length >= %d AND length <= %d";
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString,
                              minLength, maxLength];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    int entityCount = [context countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];
    if(entityCount != 0)
    {
        [fetchRequest setFetchOffset:arc4random()%entityCount];
    }

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if([fetchedObjects count] != 0)
    {
        Words * test = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        word = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [test word]];
    }

    return word;
}
```

Using an SQLite editor I already set an index manually on column zLength, but this didn't bring any speedup. Where is the bottleneck?

**EDIT:**

I figured out that getting `int entityCount = ...` is slow. But even getting all objects and then selecting one random word is slow:

```
Words * test = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:arc4random()%[fetchedObjects count]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are effectively running two fetches here, one to get the fetch count and then one to fetch the actual object. That will slow things down.

Your predicate is "backwards." Compound predicates evaluate the first expression e.g. `length >= %d` and then evaluate the second e.g. `length <= %d` only against the results of the first. Therefore you should put the test that eliminates the most objects first. In this case, `length <= %d` probably eliminates more objects so it should come first in the predicate.

Since you don't actually need the entire `Words` managed object but just the `word` string, you can set the fetch return type to `NSDictionaryResultType` and then set the property to fetch to just the `word` attribute. That will speed things up considerably.

Part of your problem here is that Core Data is designed to managed a structured object graph and you are using a random/unstructured graph so you are cutting against the grain of Core Data's optimizations.

Comment: Thanks, now I am fetching just one attribute with a fixed length determined ahead (min/max was slowing it down dramatically).

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the SQLite editor to edit the SQLite backing store for a Core Data storage. The internals of the database is private and subject to change.

Instead go the the model editor in Xcode and simply put a checkmark on the "indexed" option for the entity attribute you want indexed.

Not sure but maybe this predicate is easier to optimize:

```
NSString *predicateString = @"length BETWEEN (%d, %d)";
```

Comment: Seems that `BETWEEN` is not possible. See also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758730/predicate-search-in-core-data-causes-sigabrt-on-second-time-through-nsbetweenpre/5759570#5759570).