# How to use predicate for a range of dates

Tags: sql, cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

I've a (SQL) code-data entity with an attribute called `date`. I construct a predicate and fetch request, and declare an array to hold the results as follows

```
NSDate *firstDate = <date1>;
NSDate *lastDate = <date2>;
NSArray *dates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: firstDate, lastDate, nil];
NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: 
    @"date BETWEEN %@", dates];

NSFetchRequest * req = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"myEntity"];
NSArray * results;
```

The following works

```
results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:req error:nil];
// gets all records
results = [results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:myPredicate];
// results now has the records I wanted
```

But the following doesn't

```
req.predicate = myPredicate;
NSArray * results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:req error:nil];
```

This in the console

-[__NSTaggedDate constantValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...

It seems wrong to have to retrieve all records then filter them. Why won't the predicate work with the fetch request? Is this an SQLite limitation? I know dates are stored as `NSTimeInterval`s (ie doubles) and have tried these in the predicate instead, but similar problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSPredicate BETWEEN with NSDate causes -\[__NSDate constantValue\]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e7ff0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268272/nspredicate-between-with-nsdate-causes-nsdate-constantvalue-unrecognized-s)

Comment: Many thanks for the hint, although I still don't understand the reason. Splitting the BETWEEN into separate subpredicates works for me.

Comment: I've provided an answer for why this is crashing. That being said, you still can't use `BETWEEN` when using core data.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this is what you are looking for ..

datePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%@ <= date && date <= %@)", endDate, startDate];

and endDate and startDate are NSDate

Answer (score -1):

The reason this is crashing is because the things inside the array should not be `NSDate` instances. The should be `NSExpression` objects whose `constantValue` is an `NSDate`. The [documentation for aggregate expressions says this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html):

> The aggregate expression allows you to create predicates containing expressions that evaluate to collections that contain further expressions.

So your collection must contain expressions, not dates.