# NSPredicate BETWEEN two dates NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I want to create a `NSPredicate` with BETWEEN keyword for two dates:
my argument `e_date` is a CoreData Entity Property of type `Date`

```
let sd = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current,year: 2019, month: 1, day: 1).date!
let ed = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current,year: 2020, month: 1, day: 1).date!

let whenPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "e_date BETWEEN %@", [sd, ed])
```

I get a following exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format
>   string "e_date BETWEEN %@"'

I have tried to cast arguments to Objective-C Types but still gets the same error.

```
let whenPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "e_date BETWEEN %@", [sd as NSDate, ed as NSDate])
let whenPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "e_date BETWEEN %@", [sd as NSDate, ed as NSDate] as NSArray)
```

**What is a correct way to use NSPredicate with BETWEEN keyword?**

*** Updated ***

I have done `Clean Build Folder`and the error has gone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5269494/1801544 use `e_date > sd AND e_date < ed`

Comment: @Larme Thx for the link. A predicate with BETWEEN can be applied on a memory store and a collection types. A solution with < > works but this question is to understand why NSPredicate(format with `between` terminates with an exception. One more thing, NSPredicate doesn't know where it will be used, so it should parse correctly at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite strange, because the predicate works well the way you wrote it:

```
 let sd = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current,year: 2019, month: 1, day: 1).date!
 let ed = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current,year: 2020, month: 1, day: 1).date!

 let whenPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "e_date BETWEEN %@", [sd, ed])

 let date = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current,year: 2019, month: 10, day: 17).date!

 whenPredicate.evaluate(with: ["e_date": date]) // true
```

I suspect a bug, you may still use `<` and `>` and fill a feedback.

**EDIT**: It could be a Core Data problem, because when you use Objective-C methods and types the syntax is still correct and working...

```
let dates : NSArray = [
    DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current,year: 2018, month: 10, day: 17).date! as NSDate,
    DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current,year: 2019, month: 10, day: 17).date! as NSDate,
    DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current,year: 2020, month: 10, day: 17).date! as NSDate,
]

let whenPredicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "SELF BETWEEN %@", [sd, ed])

dates.filtered(using: whenPredicate2)
```

**EDIT2**: I confirm that with Objective-C classes your original predicate works...

```
@objc class MyEntity : NSObject {
    @objc let e_date : NSDate

    init(_ date: NSDate) {
        self.e_date = date

        super.init()
    }
}

let entities : NSArray = [
    MyEntity(DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current,year: 2018, month: 10, day: 17).date! as NSDate),
    MyEntity(DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current,year: 2019, month: 10, day: 17).date! as NSDate),
    MyEntity(DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current,year: 2020, month: 10, day: 17).date! as NSDate),
]

entities.filtered(using: whenPredicate)
```